# wpdb query not working

Tags: wpdb, sql

I have this query and its not returning anything even though I have specific user meta for 1 user.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` 
WHERE meta_key= 'referrer' AND 
meta_value LIKE '270' AND 
meta_key= 'view_type' AND 
meta_value LIKE 'invoice'
```

What is wrong with this query?

Comment: A single meta key can't have two different names and values at the same time, I think you want some ORs in there.

Comment: You need one join _per_ meta key - out of interest, why are you using SQL and not `WP_Query`?

Comment: Yes I created a Join query and it works as to why not use wp_query its because when you do complex meta queries its just to slow using wp_query.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you must use % sign for "like" so it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` 
WHERE meta_key= 'referrer' AND 
meta_value LIKE '%270%' AND 
meta_key= 'view_type' AND 
meta_value LIKE '%invoice%'
```